# Pass in any struct as interface method

Tags: go

I'm trying to create an interface that has a method which takes any struct as input. Trying to use `*interface` but not working. Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Marshallable interface {
    marshal() (*interface{}, error)
}

func Marshal(marshallable Marshallable) (error) {
    fmt.Println(marshallable.marshal())
    return nil
}


type Message1 struct {
   message string
}

func (m *Message1) marshal() (m2 *Message2, err error) {
    return nil, nil
}

type Message2 struct {
   message string
}

func main(){
   var m1 = Message1 {message: "Hello1"}
   Marshal(m1)
}
```

It gives compiler error:

```
./prog.go:31:11: cannot use m1 (type Message1) as type Marshallable in argument to Marshal:
    Message1 does not implement Marshallable (wrong type for marshal method)
        have marshal() (*Message2, error)
        want marshal() (*interface {}, error)
```

Is there any way to get this to work?

https://play.golang.org/p/NylC2ZNQR9o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the program:

1. Do not use `*interface{}`, use `interface{}`. An `interface{}` can be used to represent "any".
2. Your `Message1` struct does not implement `Marshallable`, because it does not return an `interface{}`, it returns a `*Message2`. Go type checking is strict, if it wants an `interface{}`, you have to return an `interface{}`
3. Since `Message1.marshal` has a pointer receiver, you have to send a pointer to the struct in `main`:

```
   Marshal(&m1)
```

This way, the interface you passed will have a pointer to `m1` instead of a pointer to a copy of it.

Comment: What's the difference if I replace `interface{}` with `struct{}`? It gives the same output. I guess `struct{}` is an empty literal, while `interface{}` can take on any struct, so I want `interface{}`.

Comment: `struct{}` is data, `interface{}` has a pointer to some data.

Comment: `struct{}` is a specific type (a struct with no fields). `interface{}` can be any type (all types implement an interface with no methods).

Answer (score 1):

Your code simply does not work since the message's marshal method has a receiver of type pointer and you're passing struct, not a pointer. So you need to pass &m1 in the function call.

With ptr in receiver and return type

https://play.golang.org/p/jVOVsdPTPcm

Without ptr (*)

https://play.golang.org/p/_LS6o-y4f6l

With Ptr

https://play.golang.org/p/P-2eWtYMDaf

Comment: What's the difference if I replace `*interface{}` with `*struct{}`? It gives the same output as https://play.golang.org/p/jVOVsdPTPcm

Comment: I guess `struct{}` is an empty literal, while `interface{}` can take on any struct.

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.

Comment: A `*struct{}` is a pointer to a struct with no fields. A `*interface{}` is a pointer to an interface that may contain any kind of data. Do not use `*interface{}`, that is very rarely necessary.